# Search for part strings in header python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think I've read all similar posts and haven't found what I need.

I have a bunch of .csv files which are in principle similar but may have a bit different Header names, columns are positioned differently etc. 
I call them using pd.read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv', delimiter=';')
```

Here is a part of sample csv file header:

`Index(['1. Datum', '2. Zeit', '3. Tunnellaenge. m',
       '4. Vermessung: Hor. Ablage der Maschine. mm',
       '5. Vermessung: Vert. Ablage der Maschine. mm',
      ………...
       '21. SR:Drehzahl. rpm', '22. SR:Erddruck Schild. bar',
       '23. STZ:Gesamtkraft. kN', 'Unnamed: 23'],
      dtype='object'`

I want that my code looks into the header and finds the column I want (based on part strings). 
For instance, I always need column *'3. Tunnellaenge. m'*, the name usually doesn't Change, so I would use:

```
df['length'] = df.filter(like='laenge')
```

It usually works, but what if I want to search for a keyword 'laenge' and/o 'length'?

Like in case of header *'4. Vermessung: Hor. Ablage der Maschine. mm',*. Here I want that df.filter Returns the column which includes *'Hor'* **AND** *'Maschine'*.  How could I do it? I also tried *'regex'* function, but it didn't work for me. Should it be better to use *str.contains()* function?

It is very important as I have many different CSV files and don't want to adjust the code every time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m1 = df.columns.str.contains('laenge')
m2 = df.columns.str.contains('length')
m = m1 & m2

df1 = df.loc[:, m]
```

Comment: How about `df.columns.str.contains(r'laenge|length', regex=True)`

Comment: And how could I rename the column df1 and then call it from df['Name'] ? Just using df1 is fine for plotting but I can't make computation against other columns, because it's not included in DataFrame or?

Comment: So with  df['New Column'] = df.loc[:, m] I can add a new column. I'm still not sure how to replace the column's name tho.

Comment: @Ziga - So always is returned only one column?

Comment: I want the column which is found by `df1 = df.loc[:, m]` to be renamed and then used with  df['New Column Name']